# How to autorun Skype using systemd?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, skype, systemd

I want to start skype when I log in using Systemd. I tried a lot of things but I cant make it. Is there any way to do this?
Thats how I tried to make it.

```
[Unit]
Description=SkypeStart
After=network.target
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/super_user/skypeonstart
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sh /home/super_user/skypeonstart/skypeonstart.sh
ExecStop=/usr/bin/whoa
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: `systemd` is for (system) services, not user applications. For autostarting those, you should use your desktop environment. Check for sessions/startup options in your environment (GNOME, Xfce, etc).

Comment: What errors are you getting when trying to start the service?

Answer (score 0):

I guess if u really want to do it with systemd search where skype exec is stored with which

```
which skypeforlinux
#in my case it gives me
/usr/bin/skypeforlinux
```

That make your service file with the below options.

```
[Service]
Type=onshot
Execstart=/usr/bin/skypeforlinux
```

Or based on [randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404556/randomir)'s comment:

**Add Skype to your auto-start apps in gnome.**
Press super -> gnome-tweak-tool [image] 
-> Select Startup Application -> Add Skype

Answer (score -2):

You can't, Skype isn't a service, it's an applications, systemd just work for services.